# How to tag viewmodels when registering for MVVM messages?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

Using MVVM Light, it is easy to register for certain types of messages:

```
public MyViewModel()
{
    Messaging.Messenger.Default.Register<MyObject>(this,
        new Action<MyObject>((o) => DataMember = o));
}
```

Now, I have multiple document views in my software which implies showing/hiding views when toggling between them. When a view instance is hidden, I want its registered messages to be ignored. Similarly, when a view instance is shown, I want its registered messages to be handled. Hence, a message token *per document* is required:

```
public MyViewModel(String documentID)
{
    Messaging.Messenger.Default.Register<MyObject>(this,
        documentID,
        new Action<MyObject>((o) => DataMember = o));
}
```

**The problem is, I cannot figure out where in XAML/code to specify this token!**

Sure, I can provide the `documentID` from the view...

```
public MyView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new MyViewModel("1234");
}
```

... effectively giving me the same problem. Where would I specify this "1234" value? I read about [x:Arguments Directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee795382.aspx), hoping that it would let me specify constructor arguments in `XAML`, but it seems it's only supported in `Loose XAML` :(

I can think of a couple of solutions, like having a global variable, `ActiveDocumentID`, that would be used as token when instantiating the viewmodel. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Why not use a `GUID` instead of a String for your document Id? Setting it to `new GUID()` should automatically generate a unique Id for each ViewModel without you having to define it

Comment: Yes, but when sending the messages these guids would have to be known. Also, messages may be received inside the views too. Thus, known tokens must be used.